# VFP using ARM inline assembly

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm, beagleboard

I am trying to write a simple function to use the VFP on my beagleboard. However, Iḿ getting the following error : expected ´)´ before ´:´ token. Here is the code:

```
float floatmod(float a, float b) {
float result;
        __asm__volatile__(
        "VMOV.F32 s7, %p[a]"
        "VMOV.F32 s8, %p[b]"
        "VDIV.F32 s9, s7, s8"
        "VMLS.F32 s7, s8, s9"
        :s7 "=t" (c)
        :[a] "t" (a), [b] "t" (b)
        :"s7", "s8", "s9"
        );      
        return c;
```

}

Iḿ fairly new to inline assembly so I might have made some mistakes

Comment: You might want to consider using intrinsics for this rather than raw asm - it would save a lot of time and trouble.

Comment: Iḿ trying to speed up a program- intrinsics did not help :/

Comment: Well each intrinsic maps to one asm instruction so for the above very simple case if intrinsics didn't help then raw asm is unlikely to do any better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should end each line either with semicolon `;` or with newline symbol `\n`:

```
__asm__ __volatile__(
    "VMOV.F32 s7, %p[a];"
    "VMOV.F32 s8, %p[b];"
    "VDIV.F32 s9, s7, s8;"
    "VMLS.F32 s7, s8, s9;"
    :s7 "=t" (c)
    :[a] "t" (a), [b] "t" (b)
    :"s7", "s8", "s9"
);
```

BTW, Beagleboard supports NEON, and NEON is **much** faster than VFP on Cortex-A8 (the CPU core inside Beagleboard)

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to simply use multi-line strings:

```
__asm__volatile__("
    VMOV.F32 s7, %p[a]
    VMOV.F32 s8, %p[b]
    VDIV.F32 s9, s7, s8
    VMLS.F32 s7, s8, s9
    "
    :s7 "=t" (c)
    :[a] "t" (a), [b] "t" (b)
    :"s7", "s8", "s9"
);
```

This also works in assemblers where `;` isn't a statement separator (some assemblers take semicolons as comment indicator). It still saves you from having to enter `\n` on every line.